# VBO doesn't work Dynamic (Memory Allocate)

Tags: opengl, vbo, dma

I try VBO by DMA.
but it doesn't work.

```
Svertex = new GLdouble**[nSlice+1];

Snormal = new GLdouble**[nSlice+1];
Scolor = new GLdouble**[nSlice+1];
Sindicesup = new GLbyte[3];
for(int i=0; i < nSlice+1; i++){

    Svertex[i] = new GLdouble*[nStack+1];
    Snormal[i] = new GLdouble*[nStack+1];
    Scolor[i] = new GLdouble*[nStack+1];

    for(int j=0; j < nStack+1; j++)
    {

            Svertex[i][j] = new GLdouble[3];
            Snormal[i][j] = new GLdouble[3];
            Scolor[i][j] = new GLdouble[3];

    } 
}
   ----------------------------------------------------------                    
       glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,8*11*11*3,
                    Svertex,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

I doubt glBufferData.(I maybe wrong ArrayPointer).
Please Help me.

Sorry My english is so poor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array needs to be flat.  You want one `new GLdouble[3*(nStack+1)*(nSlice+1)]` to pass to OpenGL.  You can create pointer arrays to help you index it if you want, but the flat array will be what you pass to OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Ben.I successed when this dma copy to flat array.I haven't know that the array needs to be flat.Thank you!